# Dart: What is the difference between floor() and toInt()

Tags: flutter, dart, truncate, floor

I want to truncate all decimals of a double without rounding. I have two possibilities here:

```
double x = 13.5;
int x1 = x.toInt(); // x1 = 13
int x2 = x.floor(); // x2 = 13
```

Is there any difference between those two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by the documentation:

[`floor`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/floor.html):

> Rounds fractional values towards negative infinity.

[`toInt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/toInt.html):

> Equivalent to `truncate`.

[`truncate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/truncate.html):

> Rounds fractional values towards zero.

So `floor` rounds toward negative infinity, but `toInt`/`truncate` round toward zero.  For positive values, this doesn't matter, but for negative fractional values, `floor` will return a number less than the original, whereas `toInt`/`truncate` will return a greater number.